# SqlClient.SqlException .Number = 3617 .State = 68

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

We are receiving this exception from one of our sql select statements. I cannot find error 3617 in the sysmessages table. The .Class is 25. There is no message.

We know we are getting it on Sql server 2005 servers.

I do know that this is large select that joins several tables and uses the CLR to combine and order some data.

What could be causing this error or where I could find out what the error code means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Discussion on Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/d142d0ea-5a34-4433-b717-1a1cc31ec411), see the answer from the moderator last in the post.

**Updated**: (added text from forum post):

> Error code 3617 is a system attention.   A system attention occurs
>   when the client cancels a running request.  This can happen if the
>   command times out for example.  This error is normally not sent to the
>   client however.
>
> There is a special case where this can occur that you may be hitting. 
>   When you re-use a pooled connection, the first outbound request sends
>   a special bit flag on the request to tell the server to reset the
>   connection state prior to executing the request.  This bit causes the
>   server to first clear connection state, then execute the command.  If
>   your SQL Server is under heavy load, and this bit is set, and it takes
>   a long time to reset the connection state, the client may timeout and
>   send the system attention.  This causes the reset of the connection to
>   be cancelled and in this case you can see the 3617 sent to the client.
>
> We've recently hardened this code in current release to avoid sending
>   back this specific error code as the error is spurious in nature
>   (based on timing you may or may not get this error).  In any case, you
>   can consider this error equivalent to: "A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.  Operation
>   cancelled by user."
>
> To verify if it is this issue, examine your SQL errorlog for error
>   like below:
>
> **spid51 Task abort was requested while attempting to reuse a session with SPID 51, which has been reset for connection pooling. The session
>   will be terminated.**